# Unable to load jQuery popup on window load (bpopup)

Tags: jquery, popup, bpopup

I'm trying to make a simple call to a popup jquery plugin (bpopup).

```
;(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#popup').bPopup({
            modalClose: false,
            opacity: 0.6,
            positionStyle: 'fixed'
        });
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

There is a div with the id 'popup' which should appear, however nothing is happening (no popup is even being blocked) when the window loads.

Any advice greatly appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: The page in question is very light - text only, the popup only contains text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code. Remove one of the extra `});`.

```
;(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#popup').bPopup({
            modalClose: false,
            opacity: 0.6,
            positionStyle: 'fixed'
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ergh, I am an idiot. Thanks that did it - I'll mark as solved when the time passes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , changed to use $(document).ready

```
  ;(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#popup').bPopup({
            modalClose: false,
            opacity: 0.6,
            positionStyle: 'fixed'
                });
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

window onload will wait for all the assets to be loaded so it is possible that you are loading something that takes long time

Comment: This has not altered anything, unfortunately.

Comment: @Musa window onload will wait for all the assets to be loaded, just a thought